# Python: How do I return the parent directory name of each file os.walk returns?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to return the directory name as a string from every **file** that `os.walk` finds, this is my code so far:

```
import os
def main():
    path = '/Users/Documents/GitHub/files'
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for x in filenames:
            print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(x)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

I understand that `os.path.dirname()` and `os.path.basename()` are the respective result of passing 'path' to `os.path.split()` but why is the above not working when I use `os.path.abspath()`?

Comment: The given code is working fine for me. Can you share your actual and expected output?

Comment: I am hoping to get the parent directory name that each file is located in, and not the path. ie for: '/Users/Documents/GitHub/dir1/file1' expected output = 'dir1'

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question as python 3.x, you might find `pathlib` library useful.

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/Users/Documents/GitHub/files')
for p in path.rglob("*"):
    if p.is_file():
        print(p.parent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code displays your current directory for each `x`, because `x` is just a filename (without its parent dir, which is stored in `dirpath`). Why don't you simply `print(dirpath)`?

If this doesn't answer your question, can you give the expected output?

Comment: Good thought, I was to focused on the "filename" but `print(dirpath)` returns the whole path, I was after the parent directory only, I solved it by: `print(os.path.basename(dirpath))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you need to print every file while walking in directory?
Your code walk with just printing in root, for me. 
Try out this and let me know if it helps you.

```
# Defined two function to print dir and file, then use for loop to walk in tree.
path = '/Users/Documents/GitHub/files'
def printfile(listdir, space):
    for file in listdir:
        print("/".rjust(space+1)+file)

def printdir(entrydir):
    print(entrydir[0])
    printfile(entrydir[2], len(entrydir[0]))

#wrap up 
tree = os.walk(path)
for dir in tree:
    printdir(dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, using a function of `os.walk` and [list comprehension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3)?

```
def get_dirnames(path) -> list:
    """Return a list of directories from the root path.

    Args:
        path (str): Full path to the starting directory.

    """
    dir_list = [os.path.join(root, d) for root, dirs, _ in os.walk(path) for d in dirs]
    return dir_list
```

Which will output something like this, from your root path:

```
import os

path = 'c:/users/bob/documents'
get_dirnames(path)

['c:/users/bob/documents\\Doc_Excel',
 'c:/users/bob/documents\\Doc_General',
 'c:/users/bob/documents\\Doc_Music',
 'c:/users/bob/documents\\Doc_PDF',
 'c:/users/bob/documents\\Doc_PowerPoint'
 ...]
```

If this isn't what you're after, please provide an expected output and we'll see how we can help futher.